# matlab parfor leads to larger execution time than a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a 3 dimensional grid, in which for each point of the grid I want to calculate a time dependent function G(t) for a large number of time steps and then summing the G function for each grid point. Using 4 for loops the execution time is becoming very large, so I am trying to avoid this using parfor.

a part of my code:

```
for i=1:50
    for j=1:50
        for k=1:25
            x_in=i*dx;
            y_in=j*dy;
            z_in=k*dz;
            %dx,dy, dz are some fixed values
            r=sqrt((xx-x_in).^2+(yy-y_in).^2+(zz-z_in).^2);
            %xx,yy,zz are 50x50x25 matrices generated from meshgrid
            % r is a 3d matrix which produced from a 3 for-loop, for all the points of grid
            parfor q=1:100
                t=0.5*q;
                G(q)=((a*p)/(t.^1.5)).*(exp(-r.^2/(4*a*t)));
                % a,p are some fixed values
            end
            GG(i,j,k)=sum(G(:));
        end
    end
end
```

When I am using `parfor` the execution time becomes larger, and I am not sure why this is happening. Maybe I am not so familiar with sliced and indexed variables on a parfor loop.

My pc processor has 8 threads and ram memory ddr3 8GB

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has been discussed in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174358/matlab-parfor-is-slower-than-for-what-is-wrong/3174665#3174665), `parfor` comes with an overhead. Therefore, loop that is too simple will execute more slowly with `parfor`.

In your case, the solution may be to parallelize the outermost loops.

```
%# preassign GG
GG = zeros(50,50,25);

%# loop over indices into GG
parfor idx = 1:(50*50*25)
    [i,j,k] = ind2sub([50 50 25],idx);
    x_in=i*dx;
    y_in=j*dy;
    z_in=k*dz;
    %dx,dy, dz are some fixed values

    r=sqrt((xx-x_in).^2+(yy-y_in).^2+(zz-z_in).^2);

    %xx,yy,zz are 50x50x25 matrices generated from meshgrid
    % r is a 3d matrix which produced from a 3 for-loop, for all the points of grid

    for q=1:100
        t=0.5*q;
        G(q)=((a*p)/(t.^1.5)).*(exp(-r.^2/(4*a*t)));
        % a,p are some fixed values
    end
    GG(idx)=sum(G(:));
end
```

Comment: Or even a single parfor i=1:50, in case there is still an overhead

Comment: You can check if the overhead is affected by the number of workers. For a small job, fewer workers can be sufficient

Comment: thanks @Jonas for the answer and thank you all for your comments. I focus in the inside loop and didn't think about the outermost loops. zamazalotta i 'll try it.