# How to read binary file in one block rather than using a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary, block, fread

I have this file which is a series of x, y, z coordinates of over 34 million particles and I am reading them in as follows:

```
parfor i = 1:Ntot
 x0(i,1)=fread(fid, 1, 'real*8')';
 y0(i,1)=fread(fid, 1, 'real*8')';
 z0(i,1)=fread(fid, 1, 'real*8')';
end
```

Is there a way to read this in without doing a loop? It would greatly speed up the read in. I just want three vectors with x,y,z. I just want to speed up the read in process. Thanks. Other suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have a machine with Matlab and I don't have your file to test either but I think `coordinates = fread (fid, [3, Ntot], 'real*8')` should work fine.

Comment: @Griff the slowness of your code also came from the fact that you were using a parfor in a bad situation. You should have used a simple for loop here. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3174364/1609556)

aside your use of a for loop, you were also using a parfor loop for something that was too simple. If a loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [fread](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html) is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're right.  Reading data in larger batches is usually a key part of speeding up file reads.  Another part is pre-allocating the destination variable zeros, for example, a `zeros` call.

I would do something like this:

```
%Pre-allocate
x0 = zeros(Ntot,1);
y0 = zeros(Ntot,1);
z0 = zeros(Ntot,1);

%Define a desired batch size.  make this as large as you can, given available memory.
batchSize = 10000;

%Use while to step through file    
indexCurrent = 1;           %indexCurrent is the next element which will be read
while indexCurrent <= Ntot

    %At the end of the file, we may need to read less than batchSize
    currentBatch = min(batchSize,  Ntot-indexCurrent+1);

    %Load a batch of data
    tmpLoaded = fread(fid, currentBatch*3, 'read*8')';

    %Deal the fread data into the desired three variables
    x0(indexCurrent + (0:(currentBatch-1))) = tmpLoaded(1:3:end);
    y0(indexCurrent + (0:(currentBatch-1))) = tmpLoaded(2:3:end);
    z0(indexCurrent + (0:(currentBatch-1))) = tmpLoaded(3:3:end);

    %Update index variable
    indexCurrent = indexCurrent + batchSize;
end
```

Of course, make sure you test, as I have not.  I'm always suspicious of off-by-one errors in this sort of work.