# How to convert radix sort serial code to parallel code in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, radix-sort, serial-processing

I am interested in parallel programming. I wrote a serial radix sort algorithm. Now I want to convert it to a parallel algorithm. What methodology can I apply to it in order to convert it to parallel? When I tried to apply `parfor` instead of `for`, I got the error: "valid indices for 'C' are restricted in PARFOR loops." How can this be overcome?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
function array = radixSort(array)
    maxx = max(array);
    base = 1;
while maxx/base > 0
    array = counting_sort(array,base);
    base = base * 10;
end
    function W = counting_sort(array,base)
        X = zeros(1,11);
        W = zeros(1,numel(array));
        for j = 1:numel(array)
            X(rem(floor(array(j)/base),10)+1) = X(rem(floor(array(j)/base),10)+1) + 1;
        end
        for i = 2:11
            X(i) = X(i) + X(i-1);
        end
        for j = numel(array):-1:1
            W(X(rem(floor(array(j)/base),10)+1)) = array(j);
            X(rem(floor(array(j)/base),10)+1) = X(rem(floor(array(j)/base),10)+1) - 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `parfor` you should read about the [classification of variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/classification-of-variables-in-parfor-loops.html). For a sliced variable `C` the iteration `i` may only access `C(i)` (simplified). In your case you have dependencies between the iterations of your loop, one reading the data from the previous. This makes a `parfor` impossible.

As far as I understood you code, it is not the right choice to parallelize it using the parallel computing toolbox. Assuming you get your variable indices fixed, [you will probably end up with code beeing slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174358/matlab-parfor-is-slower-than-for-what-is-wrong). This is typically when having simple computations, then the overhead of the `parfor` wastes more time than you can potentially save.

To improve the performance of your code, instead take a look at vectorization or suitable built-in functions.

Instead of

```
for i = 2:11
    X(i) = X(i) + X(i-1);
end
```

Use:

```
X=cumsum(X);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.Also cumsum function is great.You said that it is not the right choice to parallelize it using the parallel computing toolbox,What is your suggestion to parallelize it.Do I need to create the algorithm from scratch?.I think There must be a way to overcome by using any method.

Comment: To get fast running code, you can either optimize your m code or chose to implement it in c and make it available via mex.